# How can you set a custom display-name for your web.xml file in a Grails project

Tags: grails, web.xml

By default grails wants to create a web.xml display-name of:

> <appname>-<environment>-<version>

I would like this to simply be:

> <appname>

How do you set a custom display-name value for your web.xml file creation when using the normal 'grails war' or 'grails dev war' commands?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/02/grails-goodness-one-war-to-rule-them_4229.html) will help. Or you can just run `grails install-template` and override the web.xml template's display-name as your requirement. For example: `/sample-app`

Comment: Yeah I found that earlier but couldn't get his _script to work. Seems a lot like my solution of changing it after generation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom event listened. Create a `Scripts/_Events.groovy` in your project with:

```
import grails.util.Environment

// File: scripts/_Events.groovy
eventWebXmlStart = { webXmlFile ->
    println "Updating web.xml display-name (Env: ${Environment.current}"
    ant.echo message: "Change display-name for web.xml (Env: ${Environment.current}"

    def appName = grailsAppName
    if (Environment.current != Environment.PRODUCTION) {
        appName = "${grailsAppName.toLowerCase()}-${Environment.current.name.toLowerCase()}"
    }

    def tmpWebXmlFile = new File(projectWorkDir, webXmlFile)

    ant.replaceregexp (file: tmpWebXmlFile, match: "<display-name>(.+)</display-name>",
            replace: "<display-name>${appName}</display-name>")
}
```

This will modify the generated `web.xml` before plugins modify it. At this point the template has already been processed (so `@grails.project.key@` has already been replaced with appname-environment-version).

The script will open up the temporary `web.xml` and replace the entire `<display-name>` element with:

- `PROD` -> appname
- `TEST` or `DEV` -> appname-environment

---

*With thanks to [Mr Haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/grails-goodness-one-war-to-rule-them_4229.html), who describes using the script after `install-templates`*

Answer (score -1):

I don't like this solution, but I ended up running a script after the build completes to extract the web.xml file, update it & push it back into the war like so:

```
export PROJECTHOME=/aldapps/data/www/jenkins/jobs/JobName
rm -rf ROOT.war
rm -rf /tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml
cp projectName-DEV.war ROOT.war
unzip ROOT.war WEB-INF/web.xml -d /tmp
sed 's/projectName-$versionnumber/projectName/' /tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml > /tmp/WEB-INF/web2.xml
rm -rf /tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml
mv /tmp/WEB-INF/web2.xml /tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml
cd /tmp
zip -u ${PROJECTHOME}/ROOT.war WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the command `grails install-templates`, then edit `src/templates/war/web.xml`

Comment: Could you describe what changes need to be made to `web.xml`?

Comment: Thanks, I'd like something a bit more repeatable/automated though so I can do it as part of my build process.